# How to convert a RESTful URL to servlet request parameter string

Tags: spring-mvc

I am new to Spring and want to know how to convert a RESTful URL like `/test/test123.mvc/userid/123` to `/test/test123.mvc/userid=123?`

I am thinking to get the variables using the `@pathvariable` annotation and constructing the servlet string. Will that work?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, @PathVariable would be perfect for this kind of request.
But, careful about how forms URL and type of request you are dealing with.
@PathVariable won't be useful in POST types of request.
And, in GET request it should be like /test/test123.mvc?userid=123, then only @PathVariable would work.

Comment: `@PathVariable` will work fine with URLs like /userid/123 - you just need a RequestMapping including "/userid/{userid}". I'd suggest "/user/{userid}" though.